# Signal Function Analysis

Tags: signal-processing

[image]

I have attempted this problem but am unsure of what the solution should look like. I am confused specifically on the constants a and b, as well as the bounds of the function. I also do not understand the absolute value. is |h(n)| = h(|n|)?

Comment: You can write mathematic formulas using Mathjax. Please refer to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/7195

Comment: *is |h(n)| = h(|n|)* No. Try with actual numbers and see what you get! Choose some a and b, tabulate the results for n from say -10 to +10. In general, a and b could be complex - and then |h(n)| would indicate magnitude. But if h(n) is real, the magnitude of a real number is its absolute value so it all works out. Complex magnitude is the extension of absolute value function from reals to complex numbers. Since this is a pure math question, I'm not so sure if it should be on EE - perhaps https://math.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit.

Comment: *I am confused specifically on the constants a and b* Those are up to you. In general consider a and b to be complex numbers, and see what results you get for various combinations of complex plane quadrants for a and b. There are 16 possible combinations (4*4) to try. You should also find the convergence criterion - that's actually easy I hope.